How does an electron move around the nucleus according to classical mechanics?
If an electron moves around a nucleus in an elliptical path, is the moment of inertia of the electron with respect to the nucleus a constant w.r.t time?
I think that both the electron and nucleus must be in motion so as to conserve linear momentum. If I assume that both move in elliptical paths around the COM, then the abovementioned moment of inertia can be a constant only if they move in their respective elliptical trajectories while maintaining constant separation between them. Is such a motion possible? If yes, then how are the ellipses related to each other?

classically, the electron would radiate and spiral into the nucleus

What if it didn't radiate? Or if instead of electron and nucleus, we consider 2 masses, would they sill collide?

I have heard that the ratio of moment of inertia and angular momentum stays constant for isolated systems. If that is true then moment of inertia must be conserved because angular momentum is conserved for isolated systems. Does this mean that the separation between the two masses stay constant?

@PatoGalmarini not so simple, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonradiation_condition and also the references in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Adolphus_Schott

Re, "What if it didn't radiate?" OK, so you're asking, what does classical physics say would happen if the thing that classical physics says must happen doesn't happen? I'm not sure how there could be a meaningful answer to that question.

@PatoGalmarini https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.135.B281 A simple general criterion is developed, using the retarded potentials of classical electromagnetic theory, for absence of radiation from arbitrary time-periodic charge-current distributions. The criterion is applied to rigid finitely extended distributions of charge which may undergo orbital motion with period . It is found that, for this type of distribution, the condition for no radiation is that the extent  of the distribution be an integer multiple of cT. Some of these distributions may spin while orbiting...

@SolomonSlow Schott found non-radiating but oscillating charge/current  configurations; in fact, a large part of antenna design is to minimize the nonradiating action of an antenna. See the references above.

@hyportnex another result showing  that many features of QM can have classical equivalents. The hardest one is entanglement, which has classical analogs, but only for particles that interact locally. Also, another analogy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopman%E2%80%93von_Neumann_classical_mechanics#:~:text=In%20the%20Hilbert%20space%20and,wave%20function%20collapse%20of%20quantum

Forget radiation, forget QM. That's clearly totally unrelated to what the OP is asking. The OP is just asking how two masses centrally attracted by a $1/r^2$ potential would move. It's exactly the two-body gravity problem. It's a question about classical Newtonian physics, not E&M, not QM.

@Jagerber48 Then he should ask how a 1kg copper sphere carrying a charge of 1e-6C orbits a 1000kg copper sphere carrying a charge of 14e-6C. THAT would be a classical physics problem and then you would be correct. An electron does NOT move like these hypothetical copper spheres would.

@hyportnex Now disturb that special distribution by an arbitrary amount. What will it do? It will send out classical radiation that is not quantized. End of the dream of classicizing atomic physics. It is also not clear where the rigidity in such a system is supposed to come from. Not to mention that Dr. Millikan wants us to hold his oil dropper.

@Jagerber48 Precisely, in their own comment the OP says "if instead of electron and nucleus, we consider 2 masses", so this is clearly a purely Newtonian mechanics question. Instead of "electron" and "nucleus", imagine the question asked about "Earth" and "Sun".

@FlatterMann I think you have just clarified my point that it is not that an oscillating electronic current would radiate and then the atom would "collapse" but, contrary to common beliefs, there are electrodynamic systems that would not radiate (how many students/teachers know this?) and still having "stability" issues. These are very different problems.

@hyportnex There is a paper that claims that such systems exist. I have never seen one. Neither have you. There is a not so fine line between a theory paper and an actual physical system that costs a lot of money and work in the laboratory to make. Sorry, but I am an experimentalist. I need to see the real thing. Math doesn't do it for me. Honestly, as an experimentalist I wouldn't even know where to start. Can I put a surface charge on a balloon and blow periodically into it? Sure. Will that radiate? Probably not much. Is that a model for an atom? Not really...

So a hypothetical question in which the hypothetical breaks a law of physics can always be problematic, since you need to decide how to break the law of physics, and that choice cannot be justified by physics---nevertheless, ppl will attack your choice based on it violating physics, which it has to do.
tl;dr: any comments about ignoring a law of physics will ignored with equal vigor.
Your supposition is correct, for an atom with a nuclear mass $M$, one can posit:
$$ \frac 1 2 \le \frac{m_e} M \le 294 $$
which starts at the exotic atom positronium, and tops out at Oganesson-294.
That means the nucleus is not stationary.
Labeling the two particles' positions $\vec r_N$, $\vec r_e$, we have a hamiltonian (in the Coulomb approximation...and likewise for the position):
$$ H(\vec r_N, \vec r_e) =
\frac{p^2_N}{2M} +
\frac{p^2_e}{2m_2} +
V(|\vec r_N - \vec r_e|) $$
which is not fun.
We note that the position dependence can be expressed in term of the vector:
$$ \vec r \equiv \vec r_e - \vec r_N $$
moreover, it only depends on the magnitude:
$$ r= |\vec r| $$
(which means we have spherical symmetry).
Step 1 is to defined the center of mass affine position:
$$ \vec R = \frac{M\vec r_N + m_e \vec r_e}
{M+m_e} $$
with conjugate momentum $\vec P$.
Step 2 is define the reduced mass, $\mu$, associated with the coordinate vector $\vec r$:
$$ \frac 1 {\mu} = \frac 1 M + \frac 1 {m_e} $$
The Hamiltonian is then:
$$ H = \frac{P^2}{2(M+m_e)} +
\frac{p^2}{2\mu} + V(r) $$
which contains a free-particle term:
$$H_{CoM} \equiv   \frac{P^2}{2(M+m_e)} $$
and a pure Coulomb term:
$$H \equiv \frac{p^2}{2\mu} + V(r) $$
where:
$$ V(r) = \frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{Ze^2} r $$
At this point, we ignore the center-of-mass motion, and solve for the orbit (classical) or hydrogen-like atom (quantum).
As you point out in the post: yes, the nucleus undergoes 'reciprocal' motion. This means it classically is also in an elliptical orbit about the barycenter (aka: CoM), and in quantum mechanics, it is also in an orbital with a wave function $\Psi_{nlm}(\vec r_N)$ that has the same functional form as the atomic orbitals $\psi^{(e)}(\vec r_e)$.
Nevertheless, super-imposing the two motions is messy, so we call the atomic orbital
$$ \psi_{nlm}(\vec r) $$
and compute it with mass $\mu$.
The original question: "how are the two ellipses related" is that they are related by dilation symmetry, where the scale factor is a ratio of the two masses.
In the case of positronium:
$$\frac{m_e}{M} = \frac{m_e}{m_e}=1 $$
and they are identical, while for the largest atom:
$$ \frac{m_e}{M} \approx \frac{m_{AMU}/1823}{294m_{AMU}} \approx \frac{1}{536,000}$$
so the size of the ellipse (or orbital) of the nucleus is:
$$ a_N \approx 0.1\,{\rm fm} = \frac{R_p}{12} $$
where:
$$ R_p = 0.88\,{\rm fm} $$
is the proton radius.
Regarding the hypothetic part: a classical orbit radiates EM waves because charges are accelerated. Since they electron moves at:
$$ v \approx \alpha c $$
in a radius:
$$ a_0 =\lambda_C/\alpha $$
where $\alpha \approx 1/137$ is the fine structure constant, and
$$\lambda_C = \frac h {m_ec} \approx 4\times 10^{-13}
\,{\rm m}
$$
is the Compton wavelength of the electron, we can ball park the acceleration:
$$ a = \frac{v^2} r = \frac{\alpha^2 c^2}{\lambda_C/\alpha}$$
$$ a = \frac{m_e}{h}\big(\alpha c\big)^3
\approx 10^{22}\, g $$
Wow. That is big, and that is for $Z=1$. I'll leave it as an exercise to estimate the result for $Z=118$.
Quantum mechanics of course precludes this state from radiating.
(As an aside: as $Z\alpha \rightarrow 1$ this estimate runs into relativity problems as $v\rightarrow c$, and the naive radius gets down to the Compton wavelength)
